# Questions about BigDecimal ROUND_DOWN

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

The situation is like this, the expected result through the following code is 123.10 is actually 123.09, for this result is a bit ignorant, ROUND_DOWN is not truncated, why is there a calculation, 123.2000 will be truncated to 123.20, what is the principle? jdk1.8

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(123.1000);
    System.out.println(b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN));
}
```

> 123.09
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: [Related but not quite a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3419894)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor, the documentation for which states:

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing `new BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates a `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a `double` (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length).  Thus, the value that is being passed *in* to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.

The solution is to use the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("123.1000");
    System.out.println(b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN));
}
```

Which works exactly as you would expect.

```
123.10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I got it, thank you very much, I made a low-level mistake.